# How to write to an excel with different column name from dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Like in sql;

```
Select Name as EmployeeName,
      Age as   EmployeeAge
From tableA.
```

How can I write to an excel with different column name?

```
df.to_excel(writer, columns=['Date' as TimeStamp,'Id' as DeliveryId],sheet_name='sales')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not possible, need `rename` before [`DataFrame.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
d = {'Date':'TimeStamp','Id':'DeliveryId'}
df.rename(columns=d).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sales')
```

If multiple columns and want to specify them by list with parameter `columns`:

> columns : sequence or list of str, optional
>   Columns to write.

```
d = {'Date':'TimeStamp','Id':'DeliveryId'}
df.rename(columns=d).to_excel(writer, columns=["TimeStamp","DeliveryId"], sheet_name='sales')
```